# Is there a way to bulk-edit mp3 files and replace the file name with the file's title?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mp3, metadata

In a nutshell, I uploaded a few thousand songs to Google Play Music to listen from anywhere, and eventually redownloaded them when my old drive eventually died. The issue is, the downloader tool they provided made some.. interesting decisions.

The downloaded filename has the two following issues: it added "00 " to the start of effectively every non-album song (~80%), and the file name had a limit when downloading. For example: "00 Nujabes - Eclipse (Feat_ Subst.mp3", where the full title is "Nujabes - Eclipse (Feat. Substantial)". The full title was saved as the actual title of the mp3.

Unfortunately, Spotify only seems to read the file name and not the file title, so I'd have to manually copy/paste the title to the file name many many times over. Is there any way to batch transfer the file's title to be the actual file name? Aside from invalid characters.

[image: Example]

Comment: I use MP3Nity free version to do this>>>>>>>>>http://www.littlelan.com/mp3nity/downloadpg.php,, or use the free utility called Bulk File rename.version which is easier for renaming file names.>>>https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

I'd think any ID3 batch editor would help you here.

For example [Foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/) or [Mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html)

Comment: +1 for Mp3tag. The best tag editor I've found by far.

Answer (score 0):

With **PowerShell** and the `shell.application` COM object, you can do this without 3rd-party software. The [`ExtendedProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty) method is used to retrieve metadata.

- Illegal filename characters in Title replaced with `_`
- Non-zero track numbers prepended to name

```
$StartFolder    = 'C:\Downloaded\Files'
$MusicExts      = @( 'mp3' , 'wma' )            # Add desired extenstions to list
$IllegalChar    = '/|\\|:|\*|\?|"|<|>|\|'       # Regex to match illegal filename characters
$LegalReplace   = '_'

$Shell          = New-Object -com shell.application

$StartFolder , ( Get-ChildItem $StartFolder -Directory -Recurse ).FullName | ForEach {
    $Shell.NameSpace( $_ ).Items() | Where IsFolder -eq $False |
      Where { ( $Ext = $_.Name.Split('.')[-1] ) -in $MusicExts } | ForEach {
        $Track  = $_.ExtendedProperty("{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6},7")
        $Title  = $_.ExtendedProperty("{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9},2") -replace $IllegalChar , $LegalReplace
        If ( $Track )
        {
            $_.Name = ( '{0:d2} {1}.{2}' -f ( $Track , $Title , $Ext ) )
        }
        Else
        {
            $_.Name = ( '{0}.{1}' -f ( $Title , $Ext ) )
        }
    }
}
```

`FMTID/PID` values obtained from NirSoft's [Property System Viewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_property_system_view.html) ( so I guess there was a 3rd party utiltiy involved! LOL )